# Paste glue objects together run in loops

Tags: r, r-glue

I am trying to paste two glue strings together in a for loop but I am not getting desired results.
e.g. in the reproducing example I have two columns and I want to loop over first column first (once) and apply function(x) on each value of second column and so on,
but the glue code runs first column (again and again) - function(second column).

I feel the question is confusing so far, hopefully an example below with help clarify my question.

```
#Reproduible example
#sample dataframe
col_A <- rep(c("one","two", "three", "four") ,each = 3)
col_B <- rep(c("yes", "No", "Maybe"),times = 4)

df <- bind_cols(a = col_A, b = col_B)

glucode_combined <- "" # Initialize empty string

# the loop over values to create a flexdashboard

for (i in unique(df$a)){

code_A <- glue(
    "{i} \n",
    "======================================================================= \n",
    )

code_B <- df %>% 
    filter(a == i) %>% 
    arrange(b) %>%
    glue_data(

"------------------------------------- \n",
"> ColumnA: {a} | ColumnB: {b} \n",
"------------------------------------- \n",
" \n",
    )

        
glucode_combined <- paste(glucode_combined, code_A, code_B, sep = "\n")
}

writeLines(glucode_combined,"glucode_combined.txt")
```

This produces a result which looks like below (It has first part of the loop repeated over and over again

```
one 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: Maybe 
------------------------------------- 
 
two 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: two | ColumnB: Maybe 
------------------------------------- 
 
three 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: three | ColumnB: Maybe 
------------------------------------- 
 
four 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: four | ColumnB: Maybe 
------------------------------------- 
 

one 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: No 
------------------------------------- 
 
two 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: two | ColumnB: No 
------------------------------------- 
 
three 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: three | ColumnB: No 
------------------------------------- 
 
four 
======================================================================= 
------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: four | ColumnB: No 
-------------------------------------
```

However I want to produce result like below, but I am not sure what am I missing

```
one 
======================================================================= 

------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: yes 
------------------------------------- 

------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: Maybe 
------------------------------------- 

------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: No 
------------------------------------- 


 
two 
======================================================================= 

------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: yes 
------------------------------------- 

------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: Maybe 
------------------------------------- 

------------------------------------- 
> ColumnA: one | ColumnB: No 
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `paste` is vectorised, and `code_B` is a length 3 vector, so paste tries to combine the strings *for each element in code_B*. Seemingly you don't want this behaviour, so first flatten `code_B` using something like `str_flatten` from the `stringr` library:

```r
code_B <- df %>% 
    filter(a == i) %>% 
    arrange(b) %>%
    glue_data(
        "------------------------------------- \n",
        "> ColumnA: {a} | ColumnB: {b} \n",
        "------------------------------------- \n",
        " \n",
    ) %>%
    stringr::str_flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `paste(collapse = "\n")` instead of `paste(sep = "\n")`. `collapse` turns your vector into one string.